# JSON method GET accents word áéé string returns NULL (Android)

Tags: java, android, json

My code .java send the values to the database very well, but, when I use the method GET to list my database's values, if a word has accents, the string returns null, why??

I already make tests with UTF-8, but it don't works, I don't know what to do more. Please, I hope that someone help me fast!!

```
// function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
         HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
              // http client


            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {

                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
           httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
               response = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't compare strings with "==", you need to use "equals" method

Comment: Is the data being stored in the database in utf-8 format?

Comment: could it be a server side problem? Could you show a json object that is being returned with your GET request?

Comment: Consider to use: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8192);`

Comment: @user2340612: I would not be so categorical. try `System.out.println("GET" == "GET");`, you may be surprised.

Comment: @njzk2 yes it's true. But this is a very particular case, because java reuses the previously declared string for efficiency reasons, so they both have the same pointer (i.e., it is the same object). But in general it's wrong to use "==" to compare strings, as this operator compares references, not the content of the string/object. So in 99% of cases it's wrong to use "==" instead of ".equals()"

Comment: @user2340612: true. but in this case, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I used this:

Try to change

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

To

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

in method post

```
if (method == "POST") {

    // request method is POST
    // defaultHttpClient
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, , HTTP.UTF_8));

    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    is = httpEntity.getContent();

}
```